# java.lang.ClassCastException: DataCountUtilities cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Tags: java, android, class, service

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: DataCountUtilities cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Notes:

I've declared the following in my manifest - but I have a feeling it might be crashing due to the fact it isn't an activity - I simply need it to run in the background once I call it - so I'm not sure if it should be defined as a service - or simply left as a class as I have it.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.tracfone.generic.clientprovisioninghandler.DataCountUtilities">
                </activity>
```

SOURCE:

```
public class DataCountUtilities {


    //swap the content of a string by switching place
    //each pair of consecutive characters
    //If string length is odd last character is left in place
    public String swappedMdn(Context ctx){ 
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        //Extract the phone number from the TelephonyManager instance
        String mdn = tm.getLine1Number();
        //Insure MDN is 10 characters
        if (mdn.length() < 10 || mdn == null) mdn ="0000000000";
        //Extract last 10 digits of MDN
        if (mdn.length() > 10) mdn = mdn.substring(mdn.length() - 10, mdn.length()); 
        char data[] = mdn.toCharArray();
        char digit;
        for (int index = 0; index < mdn.length() - (mdn.length())%2; index+=2){
            digit = data[index];
            data[index] = data[index+1];
            data[index+1] = digit;


            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, DataCountService.class);
            i.putExtra("key", mdn);  
            startActivity(i);  

                }

        return String.valueOf(data); 


}

    private void startActivity(Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is not the correct way of using activity.If you want this class should be run in the background then declare it as `Service`.Activity is having its own life-cycle which you have to [follow](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html).

Comment: You make a good point about overall design, but this is not the answer to the immediate problem posted, which would occur with a Service as well.

Answer (score 0):

A class which you wish to have the platform invoke as an Android Activity class must extend `Activity`.

change

```
public class DataCountUtilities {
```

to

```
public class DataCountUtilities extends Activity {
```

Of course if you are not writing this as an Activity (the body doesn't particularly look like one) then you need to invoke it appropriately.  For example, if you want it to be a Service as Akshay suggests, then it would need to extend `Service` instead.  Or some subclass of either.